# Get result of last statement in JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given is a file with JavaScript-Code. For example:

```
1 + 1;
3 + 3;
```

I want to receive the value of the last expression (which is 6 in this case).

This could be achieved via

```
node --print "1 + 1; 3 + 3;"
```

But I cannot pass the code as a string because the code can contain quotes which conflict with the quotes **around** the code (e.g. node -p "1 + 1; aFunction("string")").

Unfortunately, node's --print parameter cannot deal with files.

Another approach would be to modify the source file. I could use the eval-Function which has the desired behaviour that eval("1 + 1; 3 + 3") returns 6. Unfortunately, I run into the same conflicts with the quotes.

I hope I could make my point clear. I'm looking forward to your answers.

Comment: If you're on linux you can just put the stuff in a file and then run `node -p < thefile.js`

Comment: I'm on windows, but it works here, too. Thank you! If you post this as an answer I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Linux and maybe MacOS and maybe maybe Windows/Cygwin you can put the code in a file and then try this:

```
node -p < thefile.js
```

Comment: On my Ubuntu it works fine. With and without semicolon.

Comment: @Robert yes I think my xterm tty had gone slightly insane